# How to using Gmail Smtp service with Oauth2 from a web.api

Tags: c#, web-services, email, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I am try to send emails using GMAIL OAuth protocol but the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync method hangs.

I try to run this from server (it is a web.api project that receive the send email information from the client through a htttp POST, then my service should connect to Google Gmail and send the email) Then the service act as a proxy between the Gmail and the client.

I got the client secret stuff from google console for Web Applications.

I use Visual Studio 2013 C# NET4.5. The service has access to the directory where I store the DataStore.

The code that i use is the following and hang over GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync

DbGoogleDataStore is the same implementation of DataStore as Google (I planning to create my data store in the future in the database, for that I separate it)

```
 public void SendMailUsingOauthProtocol(SmtpConfigurationSettings settings, SmtpSendMessageInputModel filter)
    {
        var msg = new AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage() // MailMessage
        {

            Subject = filter.Subject,
            Body = filter.Body64,
            From = new MailAddress(settings.Username),
        };
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(filter.To));
        msg.ReplyTo.Add(new MailAddress(filter.To));
        var msgStr = new StringWriter();
        msg.Save(msgStr);


        // Get from settings the Client secret
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(settings.AutClientSecret);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        //ClientSecrets secret = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;


        var storeFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        storeFilePath = storeFilePath + @"\GmailOauth\";
        Debug.WriteLine(storeFilePath);

        IDataStore fileStore = DbGoogleDataStore.Factory(storeFilePath, true);

        // Create the credential.. this step go authenticate with the user if it is necessary
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                stream,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                fileStore
                ).Result;

        //Create GMAIL API Service
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName

        });

        var result = service.Users.Messages.Send(new Message { Raw = Base64UrlEncode(msgStr.ToString()) }, "me").Execute();

    }
```

Please, Someone has a idea about how to do this?

Comment: can you show the code that is not working?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the used code

Comment: is any exception returned? say, after a timeout period?

Comment: Yest "A Task was canceled"

Comment: The program get the exception after a timeout period, the first exception is 'System.AggregateException' then the Inner Excpetion message is "A Task was canceled" HResult = -214633029